# Placing Text over Image

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to do is make it so that the text can be shown over the image. I put the text in an h1 tag which is inside of a div inside of the body. However, for some reason the changes aren't registering. In-fact, any changes that I make to the text that I want to be in the center of the image, those changes aren't registering at all.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/770076532433354783/770076695368564776/vice-logoFlag1.png" width="50" height="50">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="homeWording" href="/Users/nixon/Documents/Website Development/Website 1 Project/home.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Gang Database
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">The Ballas</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">The Families</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Los Santos Vagos</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Varrios Los Aztecas</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Marabunta Grande</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" id="logout" type="submit">Log out</button>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <body>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/398526333480599563/720783925395456021/TC21.png" alt="" width="100%" height="350">
      <h1>TEXT IN CENTER</h1>
    </div>


  </body>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #212529;
}

.main {
  background-color: #77857b;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 7em auto;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  box-shadow: 0px 11px 35px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
    }

#signInLettering {
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: Optima;
  padding-top: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #d8e7eb;
  font-style: italic;
}

.un {
    width: 76%;
    color: rgb(38, 50, 56);
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: #d8e7eb;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: 46px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 27px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    }

    .pass {
    width: 76%;
    color: rgb(38, 50, 56);
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: #d8e7eb;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: 46px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 27px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    }

#homeWording {
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.image {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
}

h1 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 200px;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS:

```
.image {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Possible Solution:

```
.image {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
}
```

See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GK3SZTI7KJZW)

Answer (score 0):

Just use flexbox like this

Give a higher z-index to the H1 and change the positioning of the image to absolute.

See codepen https://codepen.io/thewhitegrizzzzli/pen/xxOqdGM

```css
.image {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
  display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;
  height:350px;
}

.image img {
  position:absolute;top:0;
}

h1 {
   z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: I can see how it works in the codepen, but after applying the same exact text from your codepen to my home.html file and styles.css file on atom (respectively) and saving it, it still isn't working.

Comment: have you clearerd your cache? maybe its a cache-related display issue

Comment: Yes, I just tried clearing my cache and to no avail. Is my css file linked to my home.html file correctly?

Comment: well if your style.css is located inside //css/ then yes  (// being the root of your webapp)

Comment: you can try inlining just this part of new css code directly in your html like this, you just add this anywhere in your body `<style> CSS CODE </style>`